# Router view in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I want to create an application in which I want following functionality:

1. Some links needs to be opened in router-view which is working fine.
2. But some links i want to open in current window(means full page). But if I click on page having routerview, then it starts opening url in that routerview only.

How can we stop this?

Comment: You need to add more details. What are the components you are dealing with? What do your routes look like and which ones do you want to open in the 'router-view' vs the 'full-page' view.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for a way to set the root component. Like this:

```
import { Aurelia } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class MyCustomElement {

  static inject = [Aurelia];

  constructor(aurelia) {
    this.aurelia = aurelia;
  }

  //call this method by using click.delegate in a button
  goToAnotherPlace() {
    this.aurelia.setRoot('./your-full-page-component');
  }
}
```

By doing this, you're changing the whole page (everything inside aurelia-app attribute). You might have to configure another router.

Comment: I didn't get you. Can you please explain.